# How to mix files of compressed and stored types in the same zip file

Tags: bash, shell, zip

I am looking for a shell command (preferably a *one-liner*) that will create a zip file with both compressed, and stored content (by *stored*, I mean *uncompressed* as stated in the official documentation, link 1).

The [.ZIP File Format Specification](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) gives freedom of mixing different compression types, including just storing files :

> 4.1.8 Each data file placed into a ZIP file MAY be compressed, stored,     encrypted or digitally signed independent of how other
>   data files in the     same ZIP file are archived.

If this was necessary, this technical possibility is confirmed by the Media Type registered in the IANA registry under [application/zip](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/zip) :

> A.  Local file header:
>
> local file header signature     4 bytes  (0x04034b50)   ..
>     compression method              2 bytes

Till now I have tried unsuccessfully several zip parameters (`-f -u -U`,..)

Ideally the command would compress text files, and store binary content, differentiated by their file extension (for example : html, css, js would be considered as text, and jpg, ico, jar as binary).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for the `-n` flag?

```
-n suffixes
--suffixes suffixes

 Do not attempt to compress files named with the given suffixes. Such files are simply
 stored (0% compression) in the output zip file, so that zip doesn't waste its time trying
 to compress them. The suffixes are separated by either colons or semicolons. For example:

       zip -rn .Z:.zip:.tiff:.gif:.snd  foo foo

 will copy everything from foo into foo.zip, but will store any files that end in .Z,
 .zip, .tiff, .gif, or .snd without trying to compress them.
```

Comment: Good answer, thanks for your help. `$ zip -rn .zip foo foo
  adding: foo/ (stored 0%)
  adding: foo/2.zip (stored 0%)
  adding: foo/1.zip (stored 0%)
  adding: foo/1.txt (deflated 78%)
  adding: foo/2.txt (deflated 78%)`

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @cody's answer, you can also do this on a per-file (group) basis with `-g` and `-0`. Something like:

```
zip archive.zip compressme.txt
zip -g archive.zip -0 dontcompressme.jpg
```

> ```
> -#
> (-0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9)
>        Regulate the speed of compression using the specified digit #, where -0
>        indicates no compression (store all files), -1 indicates the fastest 
>        compression speed (less compression) and -9 indicates the slowest
>        compression speed (optimal compression, ignores the suffix list).
>        The default compression level is -6.
>
> -g
> --grow
>        Grow  (append  to) the specified zip archive, instead of creating a new one.
>        If this operation fails, zip attempts to restore the archive to its original
>        state. If the restoration fails, the archive might become corrupted.
>        This option is ignored when there's no existing archive or when at least
>        one archive member must be updated or deleted.
> ```